# content_for equivalent for Django templating

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there any way of replicating Rails' content_for in Django?

The use case is as follows:

```
# base.html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    {% yield 'head' %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>

# page.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% contentfor 'head' %}
<script type='text/javascript' src='some_library_only_for_this_page.js'></script>
{% endcontentfor %}

{% block content %}
This is the content for the page.
{% include 'widget.html' %}
{% endblock %}

# widget.html
{% contentfor 'head' %}
<script type='text/javascript' src='some_library_only_for_this_widget.js'></scirpt>
{% endcontentfor %}

<div id='the_html_for_the_widget'>
  ...
</div>
```

The behaviour of contentfor is *roughly* the same as

```
{% block %}{{block.super}}new content{% endblock %}
```

But notice that the `block.super` method won't work from inside `widget.html`.

What's the standard way of doing this in Django?

**EDIT**: The widget is included here instead of widget extending page because I may have many widgets included in a single page

Answer (score 1):

Try extending widget.html from page.html template.

Also take a look at templates in Admin app @/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates (e.g base_site.html, change_form.html)

```
# base.html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>


# page.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type='text/javascript' src='some_library_only_for_this_page.js'></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    This is the content for the page.
{% endblock %}


# widget.html
{% extends "page.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type='text/javascript' src='some_library_only_for_this_widget.js'></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}   
    <div id='the_html_for_the_widget'>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE:**
Regarding updated question.

Create a base widget class and reuse it for other widgets which would be stored in a separate module e.g. widgets.py.

These widgets should be passed to page.html template through request handling routine in e.g. views.py.

```
# widgets.py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template import Template, Context

class BaseWidget(object):  
    def content(self, content=''):
        template = '''
        <div class="w_content">
                {{content}}
        </div>
        '''
        context = {'content': content}          
        html = Template(template).render(Context(context))            
        return mark_safe(html)


class HelloWorldWidget(BaseWidget)
    def header(self):
        return '<script type='text/javascript' src='some_library_only_for_this_widget.js'></script>'

    def content(self):
        html = '<a>Hello World</a>'
        return super(HelloWorldWidget, self).content(html)


# views.py
from django.shortcuts render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from widgets import *

def page(request):
    w_headers = []
    w_contents = []
    w = HelloWorldWidget() # here you could loop through all widgets.py widgets
    w_headers.append(w.header())
    w_contents.append(w.content())
    return render_to_response('templates/page.html', {'widget_headers': w_headers, 'widget_contents': w_contents}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


# page.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type='text/javascript' src='some_library_only_for_this_page.js'></script>
    {% for header in widget_headers %}{{header}}{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    This is the content for the page.
    {% for content in widget_contents %}{{content}}{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: For the case I gave, yeah - this works. But it won't if I have 2 widgets.

Comment: Hi, i've updated the answer with another solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: This might ultimately be the way to go, but I was really hoping there was a solution to this via template tags. Many of these widgets are conditionally included in the page depending on various template variables entering from a large variety of different views.

Answer (score 0):

I use Django {% block %} template tags to build up content in exactly the same fashion...

{# page.html #}
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% include 'shared/my_widget.html' %}
{% endblock %}

Blocks can appear just about anywhere and be filled with just about anything. Any content you include in a block will be aware of objects and properties in the request context. If you're needing to pass variables to a function that then renders some content, like render_partial in Rails, you need to look into template tags.

Kind regards,
Brandon

Comment: That doesn't accomplish quite the same task. the code you've just described would put the HTML for my_widget inside the head, which doesn't make sense. There's no clean way in that setup of taking some parts of things in my_widget, putting them in the head, and some parts of things in my_widget, and putting them in the body

Comment: Sorry Jamie, it wasn't quite clear to me what you were trying to accomplish. The answer below by @tuscias is also what I would recommend doing.